# Can Apache serve resources recursively if there's a 404 in the current directory?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Is there a possibility to serve resources hosted with Apache recursively across the directory hierarchy, using *mod_rewrite* or the like?

### Example#1:

A server document `css/php/html/...` refers to the resource `image.png` at `/doc/root/dir1/dir2/dir3/image.png` (requested with `http://example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/image.png`) in the current directory. Apache serves the requested document but looks at `dir2/` if it `404s` in `dir3/`, then at `dir1/` if it `404s` in `dir2/`, etc...

I am trying to recreate Zope's ability to serve content that is higher up in the directory tree if it isn't available at the current path.

The idea is to create satellite pages further down the tree that make use of content remaining the same across all pages but that can be overridden if need be.

### Example#2:

3 sites under the same domain at `http://example.com/sites/site[1..3]/`, all pages refer to `header.png` in the current directory. For sites 1 and 2 `http://example.com/sites/site[1|2]/header.png` does not exist, but `http://example.com/sites/header.png` does - so serve this in place. For site 3 `http://example.com/sites/site3/header.png` exists, so Apache serves it as usual, ignoring `header.png` further up in the tree.

However, if `http://example.com/sites/header.png` does not exist, also check `http://example.com/header.png` and serve it in place if it exists. Only return a 404 if this doesn't exist either.

Caveat: `header.png` is just an example and it should work for all resources, be they CSS, PHP or other content and as far down the directory tree as DocumentRoot.

Can this be done, and if yes, how?

Comment: Yes, I think this can be done. Although the thought occurs that this should perhaps be handled by the application, rather than Apache? Also, "it should work for all resources" - you should be specific about which resources this should cover. Presumably you don't literally mean _everything_?

Comment: @w3dk Thanks for the application handling tip but since the logic is more dynamic on the content side than the structural/ interactional, i'd like apache to handle it and test performance once in place.
As to the resource types: why restrict? Why not allow all mime-types apache knows about and handle special files (hidden/restricted etc) as per usual? In my case, I'm looking esp. for css, html, php, png, jpg and the odd audio or video file.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following (mod_rewrite directives) in the .htaccess file in the document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?(?:[^/]+)/([^/]+)$ $1$2 [L]
```

If the requested file does not exist (`!-f`) then internally rewrite the request by removing the parent directory (`(?:[^/]+)`) from the URL. `$1` is a backreference to the part of the URL-path *before* the parent directory, ending in a slash (if any). And `$2` is a backreference to just the filename (less the slash prefix).

This applies to *every* request, except to requests in the document root (since the `RewriteRule` *pattern* will fail to match in this instance).

For example, only `/dir1/image.png` exists, then...

1. Request: `http://example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/image.png` *(does not exist)*
2. Internal rewrite to: `http://example.com/dir1/dir2/image.png` *(does not exist)*
3. Internal rewrite to: `http://example.com/dir1/image.png` *(Success!)*

For example, if `image.png` did not exist at all, then...

1. Request: `http://example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/image.png` *(does not exist)*
2. Internal rewrite to: `http://example.com/dir1/dir2/image.png` *(does not exist)*
3. Internal rewrite to: `http://example.com/dir1/image.png` *(does not exist)*
4. Internal rewrite to: `http://example.com/image.png` - 404 NOT FOUND